# An alternative to `any` when doing type safe data fetching with SWR?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, fetch, swr

The React data fetching library SWR has an example using the library with typescript [here](https://github.com/vercel/swr/tree/master/examples/basic-typescript). In the example, a fetcher function is [defined](https://github.com/vercel/swr/blob/master/examples/basic-typescript/libs/fetch.ts) that wraps fetch and which is then passed to the `useSWR` hook to do the actual data fetching.

```
export default async function fetcher<JSON = any>(
  input: RequestInfo,
  init?: RequestInit
): Promise<JSON> {
  const res = await fetch(input, init)
  return res.json()
}
```

While not immediately clear from the repo, this results in an typescript-eslint warning due to an [unexpected any](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v4.30.0/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-explicit-any.md). Below is a screen shot from my editor showing the warning:

[image: Eslint warning from my local setup]

I'm a little unclear as to what's the correct way to handle the `any` type here? Should I replace it with `unknown`? Or should I define a custom type?

Comment: Well you could perhaps capture the idea of "returns some sort of json" better by using a custom type: `type JSONV = null | string | number | boolean | {[k: string]: JSONV}; type JSONObj = Record<string, JSONV>;`, then: `async function fetcher<JSON = JSONObj>(...)`. However this will still be cumbersome to use in practice if you don't know the format of your response beforehand as it will require a lot of casting / narrowing before you can use the values. Ideally you should just specify the exact response shape at the call site: `const resp = await fetcher<{foo: string, bar: number}>(...);`.

Comment: "Should I replace it with unknown? Or should I define a custom type?" Whichever one of those